# getting a regular expression to match a full arbitrary string after an "or" statement instead of just the last character

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the following types of strings

```
href="../nicepage.css"
href="nicepage.css"
```

using this expression:

```
f="(\.\.\/|)(.)*\.css
```

however, the result for the `(.)*` inside of this statement only matches the last letter inbetween the `../` and the `.css`, so `e` instead of `nicepage`.

The full result for all the placeholders is either just `e` or `../` and `e`.

Is there a specific reason this problem occurs?

Comment: The reason is that you are repeating a capture group, giving the result of the last iteration. What do you want to match?

Comment: I would like to match the entire "nicepage", not just the e in the end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your pattern, you are repeating a capture group, capturing the last value of the iteration and also match any char using the `.` having it capture the char before the last occurrence of `.css` in the line.

You can use a capture group for the whole part after making the `../` optional, and use a negated character class not cross matching the closing `"`

You might use

```
\bhref="(?:\.\.\/)?([^\s"]+)\.css"
```

- `\bhref="` A word boundary, match `href="`
- `(?:\.\.\/)?` Optionally match `../`
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\s"]+` Match 1+ times any char except `"` or a whitespace char
- `)` Close group 1
- `\.css"` Match `.css"`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wd7PEF/1)

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following.

```
\bhref="(?:.*?\/)?([^.]*)\.css"
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/bfmD49/2)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
\bhref="    ##Matching a word boundary followed by href= here.
(?:.*?\/)?  ##In a non-capturing group matching till / and keeping it optional.
([^.]*)     ##In first capturing group matching just before 1st occurrence of . here.
\.css"      ##Matching here dot followed by css" here.
```